# Есть ли официальный code style для CSS?

Tags: css

Есть ли официальный code style для CSS? Нахожу только авторские блоги, соответственно, правила в них отличаются.

Comment: официальный для кого? или от кого? :-)

Comment: Официальный правил оформления нет, есть разве что рекомендации от ведущих разработчиков.

Comment: [например от google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю гугловский гид